# Does a disingenuous defamation lawsuit constitute malicious prosecution?

Tags: united-states, defamation

Some defamation cases (in the United States) collapse when the discovery process produces some decisive piece of evidence proving that the supposedly defamed person did what the defendant had claimed. In the US truth is a complete defense to libel.

In some of these cases, it is clear that the plaintiff must have known that the evidence existed and was just hoping it would not be found, or perhaps knew that it might be found, but wanted to harass the defendant legally anyway to force them to incur legal costs as a punishment for criticizing the plaintiff.

Now, when a plaintiff drops such a case once such evidence is found, can the defendant counter-sue the plaintiff for malicious prosecution, on the argument that the plaintiff knew that the defendants claims were based on the truth and was thus suing "maliciously"?

Comment: Plaintiffs don't prosecute - the sue. Governments prosecute.

Comment: @DaleM Malicious prosecution suits can be based on both civil and criminal prosecutions.

Comment: A civil prosecution is not the same as a civil lawsuit

Comment: And yet, a civil defendant can counter-sue a plaintiff for malicious prosecution: https://injury.findlaw.com/torts-and-personal-injuries/malicious-prosecution.html

Comment: This would vary considerably from one U.S. state to another. Some U.S. states have  what are known as "anti-SLAPP" statutes that provide an alternative to a malicious prosecution action and the law of common law malicious prosecution actions varies considerably from one U.S. state to another in most of the important details.

Answer (score 1):

> Now, when a plaintiff drops such a case once such evidence is found,
> can the defendant counter-sue the plaintiff for malicious prosecution,
> on the argument that the plaintiff knew that the defendants claims
> were based on the truth and was thus suing "maliciously"?

Presumably by "counter-sue", you were *not* intending to refer to a cross-complaint, as that would've needed to be filed before or with an Answer in the original Defamation lawsuit.

But, ostensibly, you want to know if the Defendant, after having essentially "won" against the Plaintiff, who had sued them for Defamation but had ultimately dropped the lawsuit *presumably* as a result of being unable to prove otherwise that the allegedly libelous statements were in fact false, can pursue some sort of legal remedy for all the trouble, time, and money it costed the Defendant to defend themselves, more or less, because the Defendant believes the Plaintiff...

> "must have known that the evidence existed and was just hoping it
> would not be found, or perhaps knew that it might be found, but wanted
> to harass the defendant legally anyway to force them to incur legal
> costs as a punishment for criticizing the plaintiff."

Well...

### The Short Answer

Generally speaking, since the Plaintiff dropped the case and no ruling was technically made in favor of the defendant nor the plaintiff, then the more appropriate tort you're looking for is to sue for an **Abuse of Process** (not *Malicious Prosecution* per se, because the Defendant did not ultimately get *prosecuted* for a crime--depending on the jurisdiction, a judgement against the defendant may even be a requirement to even begin considering a cause of action for Malicious Prosecution).

Technicalities aside, while the Defendant ultimately has that option, there are a number of important considerations that should be taken into account before starting off on yet another lawsuit against the party they just finished defending themselves against. So while, the defendant ***can*** file a lawsuit for Abuse of Process against the former Plaintiff, this is where we end up having to explain the long answer...

### The Long Answer

In an attempt to keep it brief, the former Defendant has to keep in mind that if they pursue an abuse of process lawsuit against that former plaintiff, they would need to prove by a preponderance of evidence that the plaintiff was not only fully aware of the purported evidence existing that would ultimately make his case fall on its face, but also that the plaintiff had an ulterior motive when filing their lawsuit against the defendant.

The more obvious issue here is that the Plaintiff ultimately dropped the case when that evidence was brought into discovery. In short, it can be easily perceived that he realized he had no chance of winning and dropped the lawsuit which makes it difficult to prove that the plaintiff had an ulterior motive set on looking to "punish" the defendant. Perhaps if the Plaintiff continued to drag the case out, propound overly oppressive discovery or in some way attempted to further draw out the lawsuit amidst an inevitable loss, ultimately forcing both parties to incur more attorney fees and/or legal costs, then there might be a slightly better chance of being able to prove the plaintiff had an ulterior motive all along. Needless to say, it's somewhat of an uphill battle.

To be precise, the [elements for an abuse of process](https://www.law.cornell.edu/wex/abuse_of_process) include:

- The existence of an ulterior motive or improper use of process, such as improper harassment
- An improper act in the use of the process that undermines legal proceedings
- (and in some jurisdictions) Harm to a litigant

So depending on the jurisdiction, the defendant would have to make a case proving at least two of those elements were present. At this point it's worth pointing out that even if the damaging statements were true, if the truth did somehow damage the former plaintiff's business or reputation, then it wouldn't be too difficult for that same plaintiff, acting as a defendant, to argue that he was motivated by a sincere concern for his reputation when he initially filed the lawsuit but proceeded to drop the suit once it had been revealed to him that he had no legal right to bring the suit.

Aside from that, assuming attorneys were involved in the original litigation, if the former Plaintiff's counsel had any prior knowledge of their client's alleged ulterior motive, they would've had an [ethical and moral obligation](https://www.americanbar.org/groups/professional_responsibility/publications/model_rules_of_professional_conduct/rule_1_16_declining_or_terminating_representation/) to either advise their client against pursuing such action or would have otherwise been obligated to terminate their client relationship. That being said, I won't speak on how the courts generally view abuse of process cases or malicious prosecution cases for that matter, but the general idea is that they can be challenging in their own right because you'd have to go after both the former plaintiff and his counsel (if applicable).

### In Closing

While I can totally empathize with the Defendant's grievance and position, and trust me, I make no exaggeration when I say I absolutely understand as I'm presently dealing with a much more tenacious and vivacious litigant in two separate lawsuits, but it really comes down to that defendant asking themselves, is it worth it? Granted, you may be able to add some other grievances to the case aside from just abuse of process, such as intentional infliction of emotional distress or what have you, but it's not going to be an easy case to win and it could be dragged out for over a year. Sometimes it's worth just walking away so that you can more quickly get that person out of your life. But, as always, seek the advice of a licensed attorney and really consider what you hope to get out of it. Sure, the Plaintiff may have dragged that defendant into something that ultimately led to nothing, but at least for now, there's the option of letting it end there.

Answer (score -4):

The practical answer is that it probably wouldn't be worthwhile even if you could.

Number 1 : I don't know the jurisdiction. I'll infer from your reference to the U.S. that you're somewhere in the U.S. or at least inquiring about U.S. law. This is state law, which varies wildly from state to state. Without knowing at least the state you're in, there's no way to say anything about what suit you could file.

Number 2 : "In some of these cases, it is clear that the plaintiff must have known that the evidence existed and was just hoping it would not be found,"

This is key. It may be clear, but that doesn't mean it can meet the required burden of proof to win a lawsuit.

Number 3 : "but wanted to harass the defendant legally anyway to force them to incur legal costs as a punishment for criticizing the plaintiff."

This would just be stupid. This is tort case. The loser pays the costs for both sides.

Number 4 : "plaintiff knew that the defendants claims were based on the truth and was thus suing 'maliciously'"

In a land where most people believe in a big daddy in the sky, it's less than nothing to believe that the plaintiff may have honestly believed in his innocence. Unless he confesses, there's no way to know. And it's incredibly difficult to convince a jury to hold someone liable.

Number 5 : And then there's the issue of what damages (money) you could win. Keep in mind, that the countersuit is in tort, so the loser pays all costs. That's a big risk. What's the potential reward? The plaintiff already paid the legal fees. So you don't need to recover that. What uncompensated costs did the defendant incur? Assuming you could get punitive damages, how much could they be?

Comment: In the United States, the loser does not normally pay costs in civil lawsuits, so a fundamental assumption of your answer is wrong.

Comment: @Cicero Actually the loser usually does pay "costs" in U.S. civil lawsuits, but that term is defined narrowly to exclude attorneys' fees and instead only includes other out of pocket costs often from a narrowly defined list, and in fairness, the question is using the term "costs" colloquially to mean attorneys' fees even though that is not how the term is used in legal language. There are circumstances, however, when attorneys fees can be recovered that are exceptions to the "American rule" regarding attorneys' fees, such as for groundless and frivolous actions and under state anti-SLAPP laws.

Comment: "it's incredibly difficult to convince a jury to hold someone liable." Juries hold someone liable thousand of times a week. It isn't that hard. "And then there's the issue of what damages (money) you could win." Juries have wide discretion to impose non-economic damages (e.g. pain and suffering and emotional distress) and punitive damages, in cases of intentional misconduct in tort, in most states.

Comment: "It may be clear, but that doesn't mean it can meet the required burden of proof to win a lawsuit." In a civil lawsuit the burden of proof is a preponderance of the evidence (i.e. more likely than not), and defendants are required to disclose documents harmful to them (e.g. emails and text messages) that are in their control, in discovery, which often very effectively reveal knowledge and intent. Third-parties (e.g. ISPs) can also be subpoenaed to obtain evidence.